# Strange symbols in Hue

Tags: sql, impala, hue

I am running a query in hue and as result I take values with this symbol:

```
ted�
nick� koro
```

Is this has to do with ASCII or UNIX? I do not have access to the source data.

Comment: Locale issue?..

Answer (score 0):

This result is sticky unicode characters , u can select it and convert it to nvarchar

```
Select Cast(table.? as nvarchar(50)) from table
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I am pretty sure that impala does not support nvarchar type like sql server

Comment: I'm not sure about impala but it has a string data type, can you use it?

Comment: The column type is a string. I tried but it is the same.

Comment: So Impala doesn't have full support for unicode. See more here:
https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_string.html

Comment: For any national language aspects such as collation order or interpreting extended ASCII variants such as ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-2 encodings, Impala does not include such metadata with the table definition. If you need to sort, manipulate, or display data depending on those national language characteristics of string data, use logic on the application side.